# Retrieve Cells w/ Data and Stop Once at Empty Cell openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am writing a Python script that leverages the OpenPyXL module to open an excel sheet that has a column of data that I'd then like to be put into a list for future usage. I've created a simple function to complete this task but I wasn't sure if there was a more effective manner in which to approach this task. Here is what I have right now :

```
import pyautogui
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('120.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')


def dataGrab(sheet):
    counter = 0
    aData = []
    while 1 > 0:
        cell = "A"+str(counter)
        print(cell)
        wo = sheet[cell].value
        print(wo)
        if wo is None:
            break
        aData.append(wo)
        counter += 1
    print(aData)
    return aData

aData = dataGrab(sheet)
```

So in essence what happens is the workbook is opened and then an infinite loop kicks off. While in this loop I am making the cell identifier ( A+counter ) to make things like "A1" and so on to then be passed to the line that gets the value of the cell which is then just appended to an existing list. This loops forever until wo is "None".

This works perfectly fine and yields no errors, I am more looking for suggestions to improve the function or know if I "did it right". Thank you for your feedback!

PS : The line "wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('120.xlsx')" takes a good 30-45 seconds to run. Any way to make that go faster? Not priority.

Comment: Please do not use `ws['A1']` for programmatic access where you make the coordinates yourself. If you only need to read large files then use read-only mode, and note that your performance will be hammered if you continue to use ad-hoc access. Please refer to the current version of the documentation for more examples.

Comment: @CharlieClark , your feedback is valuable to me and I appreciate the time you put into what you wrote. I am not sure what you mean by "ad-hoc access". Could you please elaborate or provide a reference to compare between "ad-hoc" and "Non-ad-hoc" ? :)

Comment: By "ad hoc" I mean the kind of stuff you're likely to do in a Python shell where you can appreciate the convenience of the conciseness: `ws['A1']` makes a lot of sense for anyone working directly with a workbook. Programmatic access can afford to be more verbose `ws.cell(row=1, column=1)` because the computer runs it and it is faster and more flexible. 

For what you want to do, you must treat each worksheet as a collection of rows if you want it to be fast.

Comment: @CharlieClark , I think I understand what you are saying so rather than iterating through individual cells take the entire column at once. That sounds great but I am not sure how to indicate how many rows to collect. I will try to do more research to figure this out. Thank you! (( Any cheat-sheets or links would be appreciated! :D ))

Comment: @CharlieClark , I did a little testing and I found that it was that specific excel document I was reading from that caused the delay for reasons that are escaping me. All my other test excel documents come up near instantly. :)

Comment: Don't think in terms of columns. There are no cheat sheets, just the documentation. Please use the mailing list for general questions. I think this one should be closed.

Comment: Agreed this one may be closed.